# ggvis plot disappears at random Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a strange problem in Shiny. My shiny app has one ggvis plot with `layer_points()` and several options to manipulate the plot . When I run my app sometimes everything works good even if I change all options, but sometimes ( I suppose there is no specific rule) plot disappers. Plot comes back when I change one of options but it is not cool.
I study this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/351) but I do not really know whether it is a solution for my problem.
When the plot disappears my Shiny app looks like:

[image]

This my code:

**ui.R**

```
library(ggvis)
library(markdown)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      h3("Title"),
      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               wellPanel(
                 radioButtons("radio",h5("Select"),choices=list("All values","Selected values"),
                              selected="All values"),

                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.radio != 'All values'",
                   checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup",label = "",
                                      choices,
                                      selected = c("AT1","AT2"))
                 ),
                 hr(),
                 radioButtons("dataset", label = h5("Drilldown"),
                              choices = list("2 Level" = "df1", "3 Level" = "df2")

                 ),
                 hr(),
                 h5("Choice"),
                 selectInput("xvar", h6(""), 
                             axis_vars_x,
                             selected = "value"),
                 selectInput("yvar", h6(""), 
                             axis_vars_y,
                             selected = "number2"),
                 hr(),
                 uiOutput("slider")
               )
        ),
        column(9,
               ggvisOutput("plot")
        )
      )

    )
  )
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           df2 = df2,
           df1 = df1)
  })

  axis_vara_y <- reactive({
    switch(input$yvar,
           number = 2,
           number2 = 3)
  }) 


  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("inslider",h5(""), min   = round(min(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)-1, 
                max   = round(max(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)+1,
                value = c(round(min(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)-1, 
                          round(max(datasetInput()[,axis_vara_y()]),0)+1),
                step  = 0.5)
  })

  data <- reactive({
    filteredData <- datasetInput()
    axisData <- axis_vara_y()

    if(!is.null(input$inslider)){
      if(input$radio == "All values"){
        filteredData <- filteredData %>%
          filter(filteredData[,axisData] >= input$inslider[1],
                 filteredData[,axisData] <= input$inslider[2])
      }
      else {
        filteredData <- filteredData %>%
          filter(value %in% input$checkGroup,
                 filteredData[,axisData] >= input$inslider[1],
                 filteredData[,axisData] <= input$inslider[2])
      }
    }
    return(filteredData)
  })  

  data_point <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      mutate(id = row_number())

  })

  xvar <- reactive(as.symbol(input$xvar))
  yvar <- reactive(as.symbol(input$yvar))

  dotpoint_vis <- reactive({

      xvar_name <- names(axis_vars_x)[axis_vars_x == input$xvar]
      yvar_name <- names(axis_vars_y)[axis_vars_y == input$yvar]


    data_point_detail <- data_point()

    plot <- data_point_detail %>%
      ggvis(x = xvar(),y =  yvar()) %>%
      layer_points(size := 120,fill = ~value) %>%
      add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
      add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
      set_options(width = 750, height = 500, renderer = "canvas") 

  })
  dotpoint_vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")

})
```

**global.R**

```
choices <- list("Value1" = "AT1", "Value2" = "AT2",
                "Value3" = "AT3", "Value4" = "AT4",
                "Value5" = "AT5", "Value6" = "RT1",
                "Value7" = "AT6", "Value8" = "AT7",
                "Value9" = "AT8", "Value10" = "AT9",
                "Value11" = "AT10", "Value12" = "RT2")

levele <- c("AT1","AT2","AT3","AT4","AT5","RT1","AT6","AT7","AT8","AT9","AT10","RT2")

df1 <- data.frame(value = levele,number = seq(2,46,4), number2 = seq(2,24,2),order = 1:12) 

df2 <- data.frame(value = levele,number = rep(4:15), number2 = rep(4:9,each = 2),order = 1:12) 

df1$value <- factor(df1$value, levels = levele)
df2$value <- factor(df2$value, levels = levele)

axis_vars_y <- c("number","number2")
axis_vars_x <- c("value", "order","number","number2")
```

**update**

I also do not know what happened with animation in ggvis.

Comment: @cdeterman, Do you know if it possible to fix it?

Comment: Did you update shiny and ggvis to new versions? After I did the update, the issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was difficult to reproduce at first, but I found I can reproduce it by clicking back and forth between All Values and Selected Values. The graph disappears or reappears after some number of switches between the two radio buttons, but it varies seemingly randomly -- sometimes it takes 4 clicks to make the graph disappear or reappear and other times it takes 2 clicks or some other number of clicks.

**There must be a bug in bind_shiny() or ggvisOutput()**, because the following changes do create a graphic that does not seem to disappear:

In ui.R, make this change:

```
   # ggvisOutput("plot")
   plotOutput('plot')
```

In server.R, make this change:

```
plot(data_point_detail[ , c(input$xvar, input$yvar)], xlab=xvar_name, ylab=yvar_name)
#     plot <- data_point_detail %>%
#       ggvis(x = xvar(),y =  yvar()) %>%
#       layer_points(size := 120,fill = ~value) %>%
#       add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
#       add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
#       set_options(width = 750, height = 500, renderer = "canvas") 
#     plot
```

and

```
output$plot <- renderPlot(dotpoint_vis())
# dotpoint_vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
```

Comment: Obviously that doesn't look the way you want it to -- It is just to show that plotOutput() and renderPlot() work, where ggivisOutput() and bind_shiny() don't work.

Comment: I excluded `add_tooltip` code because it extremely important for me, that's why I have to use `ggvis`. So this is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: At first I thought the problem might be how you use dotpoint_vis. You define it as a reactive and would normally refer to the results later as dotpoint_vis() but you omitted the parens and said dotpoint_vis %>% bind_shiny("plot"). If you put the parens in, you get an error. The help for bind_shiny claims it can accept a reactive expression, but to avoid that error you need to put it within an observe(), so observe( dotpoint_vis() %>% bind_shiny("plot") ) will run, but that doesn't fix your original problem. I still think there must be a bug in bind_shiny().